# Neo4j spring-security

Tags: spring-security, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is a graph database like Neo4j well suited for storing "users" and information against which spring-security checks access rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some stuff in the manual about this: http://spring.neo4j.org/docs#d0e816

Lasse

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Somehow I missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mmh,
I think that would be highly possible, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html for an example?

Comment: How would I use spring-security with the structure shown at that link?

Comment: You would build a domain model in Spring that results in this structure, and then hook up spring security against similar graph queries as stated in the example. Not sure what the exact domain model in SDN would look like. Feel free to suggest that!

Comment: The link exists no more. Please change your answer